# Create a Java/Java EE routine to send mails

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

For an account management system, i need to send an email to the users in database which have XX days remaining for their subscription.

The idea is to create a function in my Java EE code (the application in written in Java/Java EE with VAADIN 7.2 framework) which checks remaining time of each users, and sends an email if the remaining time is XX days with my MailEngine() class;

The problem is that i don't know how to create a daemon like that in Java/Java EE, or call a function everyday at 12:00 PM for example.

The solution can be to create a Java App witch is called by crontab everyday but the best solution is to do it in my Java EE application, then it'll be fully customizable (change mail body/ title in the web interfaces, for admins who are not developers).

EDIT:

I tested this code sent by joseripla

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;

@Singleton
public class MarketingMailEngine {
    int count = 0;
    //Print to log every 5 seconds
    @Schedule(second="*/5", minute="*", hour="*", persistent=true)
    public void print() {

        System.out.println(count);
        count++;
    }
}
```

But it only prints 0, even if i wait for some minutes (it should do it every 5 secs).

Comment: Hi!, that's not exactly my code ;). By the way, i test the MarketingMailEngine class in a Weblogic 12.1.2 and it's running ok. What is your application server¿?.

Comment: i use tomcat7 as server

Comment: Try with TomEE which is an "Java EE 6 Web Profile certified stack" or with anohter JavaEE aplications server (if you want to use JavaEE)

Comment: If you want to use Java SE try with ScheduledExecutorService http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html or Quartz. Hope this help you.

Comment: @joseripla I can't use another application server, only tomcat7 because all of the application runs on it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for your problem is use the Java EE Scheduled Time Service [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html)

Some basic code :

```
import javax.ejb.Schedule;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Singleton
public class SampleTask {

    @Inject
    private org.slf4j.Logger logger;

    //Print to log every 5 seconds
    @Schedule(second="*/5", minute="*", hour="*", persistent=false)
    public void print() {

        String m = "********** --------- CRON-TASK ---------- *********";
        logger.info(m);
    }
}
```

And it's done.

Comment: Will try this tomorrow and tell you if it's the answer i'm looking for =)

Answer (score 0):

It's rather off topic to recommend a tool, but what you are asking is exactly what [quartz scheduler](/http://quartz-scheduler.org/) is made for.

You can start it and stop it in a servlet context listener. It is a well maintained application, with extensive documentation and tutorials, and it is the scheduler used by Spring framework.